# io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException from IDE

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have the access to my kubernetes cluster (eks).
whey I use

`kubectl get configmaps`

I have all the grants to list all the pods.
When I try to run an app which is using https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8 from my local ide (the seme host where I used kubectl), I got this runtime error during the startup :

````
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing:
 GET at: https://xxxxxxxxx.gr7.eu-central-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/configmaps/phygital-foobarmanagement-us. 
Message: Forbidden! User arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:198373991235:cluster/inventia-ci doesn't have permission. configmaps "phygital-foobarmanagement-us" is forbidden: 
User "system:anonymous" cannot get resource "configmaps" in API group "" at the cluster scope.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:472)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:409)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:381)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:344) ```
````

like the application (which is running in the allowed host) is trying to use system:anonymous login information.

How I can tell it to use my local grant?

Than you in advance